# Having multiple dynamic imports in nextjs

Tags: javascript, import, next.js

I am using NextJS's dynamic import feature to optimise my server-side rendering. This code works, but how can I optimise it to avoid calling import on the same path so many times?
My code:

**Index.js**

```
export { default as A } from ‘./A’;
export { default as B } from ‘./B’;
export { default as C } from ‘./C’;
```

**App.js**

```
const A = dynamic(() => import(‘../abcs’).then(module => module.A));
const B = dynamic(() => import(‘../abcs’).then(module => module.B)); 
const C = dynamic(() => import(‘../abcs’).then(module => module.C)); 

...

Use A, B, C
```

Comment: This is a well-known issue. Unfortunately, there is nothing that can be done (at least for now). https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13139